# Red lines for added modules in CMake

Tags: azerothcore

I am trying to set up a personal server for the first time. I followed the install guide on the website and got the server running, but I decided I wanted to add a couple of modules - `solocraft` and `solo-lfg` since I don't plan on having anyone else on the server. I followed the listed instructions for adding both modules, but I'm a bit concerned I didn't do one step right:

> "Import the SQL to the right Database (character)" for solocraft

What I did was, after copying the folder into `C:\Azerothcore\modules`, I went to the `characters` database in HeidiSQL, and under File "Import settings file..." and selected the SQL file from the `solocraft` module. Executing that resulted in 2 warnings, but I don't see them knowing what they might be. When I attempted to continue anyway with CMake, both modules were highlighted in red during configuration.

I have virtually no programming knowledge, so I can follow directions well, but can't really interpret any of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit configure again, the modules should turn to black text and lose their red highlight. CMake shows any changed entries with a red highlight to get your attention, it doesn't necessarily mean there's an issue with the entries.